# Typescript Redux Type error of action.payload in Slice file

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a problem adding a type to action.paload in the Redux Toolkit.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface InputState {
  user: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string | null;
    userID: number | null;
  };
}

const initialState: InputState = {
  user: {
    firstName: "individual",
    lastName: null,
    userID: null,
  },
};

export const inputsDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "inputsData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action: PayloadAction<string | number | null>) => {
      const data: string = action.payload;

      switch (data.id) {
        case "firstName":
          return void (state.user.firstName = data.value);
        case "lastName":
          return void (state.user.lastName = data.value);
        case "userID":
          return void (state.user.userID = data.value);
        default:
          return;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { setValue } = inputsDataSlice.actions;
export default inputsDataSlice.reducer;
```

data.id and data.value still show me an error: `Property 'value' / 'id' does not exist on type 'string'`.

Where is the mistake please? With PayloadAction, I have exactly the specified types `<string | number | null>`.

Answer (score 0):

You yourself are specifying

```
const data: string = action.payload;
```

also, `<string | number | null>` would mean that `action.payload` is `string`, `number` or `null`, not `action.payload.value`, which you are accessing here by accessing `data.value`